# Type mismatch for a range that I have named in the manager

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I was hoping someone could help me figure out why I am getting a type mismatch in this instance. I would have expected the range variable "returnDetectionRange" and the object in the name manager called "returnChangeDetectionRange" to both be of the type Range but I am getting an error.

```
Dim returnDetectionRange As Range

Set returnDetectionRange = ActiveWorkbook.Names("returnChangeDetectionRange")
```

In the name manager, returnChangeDetectionRange refers to a dynamic range using an offset formula:

```
=OFFSET(Returns!$D:$D, 0, 'Market Value'!$E$2)
```

Thanks for taking the time to look at my question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close, but need to use the `Name.RefersToRange` property:

```
Set returnDetectionRange = ActiveWorkbook.Names("returnChangeDetectionRange").RefersToRange
```

Comment: +1, `.RefersToRange` flew under my radar until this moment and is the simplest solution to this issue. Great stuff!

Answer (score -1):

The `ActiveWorkbook.Names` collection contains `Name` objects, not `Ranges`. Tricky, amirite?

This assignment ought to work assuming the named range is always "returnChangeDetectionRange":

```
Set returnDetectionRange = Range("returnChangeDetectionRange")
```

If you were hell-bent on working with the `Names` collection, you could use this little script in the book containing the named range:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CoolNamedRangeTest()

Dim Nm As Name '<~ we'll use this to iterate through ThisWorkbook.Names 
Dim returnDetectionRange As Range

For Each Nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
    If Nm.Name = "returnChangeDetectionRange" Then '<~ check the name
        Set returnDetectionRange = Range(Nm.Name)  '<~ assign the range
    End If
Next Nm

MsgBox (returnDetectionRange.Address) '<~ validate that it worked here

End Sub
```

Comment: I downvoted because the second part it unnecessarily complicated and the first part should qualify the range, and perhaps the name, by its worksheet. You're overall point about just using the range is a good one, I think.

Comment: Candid feedback appreciated. The second part was a contrived example ("If you were hell-bent on working with the `Names` collection..."). I wholeheartedly agree that ranges should be qualified, which leads to a question -- **what if the named range is scoped only to the** `Workbook` **and not a specific** `Worksheet`? Regardless, the `RefersToRange` technique is slick and deserving of the upvotes and a green check. Thanks Doug!

Comment: Thanks Dan. Your question about the scope of a workbook-level name is an interesting one. `RefersToRange` eliminates the need for scoping, I think, in that it will find the range on the one sheet it's on. This could be useful if you know you've got such a name, but don't know what sheet it's on, but I'm having trouble thinking of a realistic example :).